# Assign from object to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have the following JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": "bitcoin", 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "11735.0", 
    "price_btc": "1.0", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "8281180000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "197517206570", 
    "available_supply": "16831462.0", 
    "total_supply": "16831462.0", 
    "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
    "percent_change_1h": "0.07", 
    "percent_change_24h": "2.17", 
    "percent_change_7d": "0.21", 
    "last_updated": "1517160566"
  }
]
```

I need to assign the value from `"price_usd"` to some variable using `$.getJSON()`.

This doesn't work

```
$.getJSON("test.js",function (data) {
        var test = data.price_usd;  
}
```

Comment: `data` is an array, not a JavaScript plain object, you can use `data[0].price_usd`

Comment: Your data is in an array, try `data[0].price_usd`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the index of the array, in this case

```
 var test = data[0].price_usd;
```

**DEMO**

```js
var data = [
{
    "id": "bitcoin", 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "11735.0", 
    "price_btc": "1.0", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "8281180000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "197517206570", 
    "available_supply": "16831462.0", 
    "total_supply": "16831462.0", 
    "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
    "percent_change_1h": "0.07", 
    "percent_change_24h": "2.17", 
    "percent_change_7d": "0.21", 
    "last_updated": "1517160566"
}
];
var test = data[0].price_usd; 
console.log(test);
```